# Using a helper class easily in expressjs

Tags: node.js, express, helper

I'm using a pretty barebones expressjs app and want to add a library/helper to store some useful code. Ideally, I'd like it to work as a module. However, I'm unable to get it to work. Here's what I've got:

```
// helpers/newlib.js
var NewLib = function() {
  function testing() {
    console.log("test");
  }
};

exports.NewLib = NewLib;
```

.

```
// controllers/control.js
var newlib  = require('../helpers/newlib').NewLib;
var helper = new NewLib();
helper.testing();
```

.

The error I get is `ReferenceError: NewLib is not defined`. I followed the design pattern (of how `exports` works) based on another simple module I downloaded.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems with your code.

First, you are assigning the `NewLib` function from *helpers/newlib.js* to `newlib` var, so you should use `new newlib()` not `new NewLib()`:

```
// controllers/control.js
var newlib  = require('../helpers/newlib').NewLib;
var helper = new newlib(); // <--- newlib, not NewLib
helper.testing();
```

Or you can rename your variable to `NewLib`:

```
// controllers/control.js
var NewLib  = require('../helpers/newlib').NewLib;
var helper = new NewLib(); // <--- now it works
helper.testing();
```

Second, the `testing` function is not accessible outside the constructor scope. You can make it accessible by assigning it to `this.testing` for instance:

```
// helpers/newlib.js
var NewLib = function() {
  this.testing = function testing() {
    console.log("test");
  }
};
```